# If a .midi is a sequence(d audio), what is a .wav or .mp3?

Tags: single-word-requests, computing, sounds

If a .midi is sequence(d audio), what is a .wav or .mp3? Streamed audio? Wave audio?

Edit: I know what the difference is/what they are, I'm asking about the terminology.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ tag=audio;   https://sound.stackexchange.com/ tag=audio-recording

Comment: http://www.toptenreviews.com/software/articles/audio-file-types/

Comment: @Kris I know what the difference is, I'm asking about the terminology.

Comment: They are all just files.  .wav and .mp3 are audio files.  In each, the audio is encoded in a particular way, but if you were to open them you would just see a long list of either binary or hexadecimal characters.

Comment: I know what they are, I'm asking about the terminology.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about audio engineering, not English.

Comment: But the question isn't about audio engineering. It is about the terminology used to describe the type of audio you get in .mp3, .wav, .flac, .ogg etc files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the contents may be streamed, it doesn't make sense to call a file format *streamed*. *Wave audio* works, though you might want to add *compressed* in the case of .mp3.

You could also describe these files as *recordings* in many cases, though of course it's possible to synthesise directly to a file.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) the WAV or WAVE format is known as "Waveform Audio File Format", and that it's sometimes called Windows Audio format. [Wikipedia also says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3) that the MP3 format, developed by the Motion Picture Experts Group (hence the "MPEG" format), is formally named "MPEG-1 Audio Layer III or MPEG-2 Audio Layer III", being the audio component of both the MPEG-1 and MPEG-2 multimedia formats.